# Error running r.thin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion

I get the following error when running r.thin:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~4/QGIS3/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\grass7\Grass7Algorithm.py",
>   line 395, in processAlgorithm outputs[outName] = parameters[outName]
>   NameError: name 'QgsProcessingOutputHtml' is not defined

Execution failed after 5.26 seconds

I looked at the Python script containing that section of code:

```
# Return outputs map
        outputs = {}
        for out in self.outputDefinitions():
            outName = out.name()
            if outName in parameters:
                outputs[outName] = parameters[outName]
                if isinstance(out, QgsProcessingOutputHtml):
                    self.convertToHtml(parameters[outName])

        return outputs
```

Thinking that a function wasn't called to start with, I added this to the call for the function:

```
from qgis.core import (Qgis,
                       QgsRasterLayer,
                       QgsApplication,
                       QgsMapLayer,
                       QgsProcessingUtils,
                       QgsProcessing,
                       QgsMessageLog,
                       QgsVectorFileWriter,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterDefinition,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingOutputHtml,
```

I still get the error. Is this a missing function, or is does this function exist anymore? I loaded the latest QGIS version (3.0.1).

Comment: I'm getting a similar error when I try to a Grass (r.watershed) algorithm in Processing Modeler. But the algorithm result does get produced. So if you ask to save the output, the file gets saved.

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the QGIS development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.