# Creating mean raster layer from set of raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have 52 weekly raster layers in QGIS. How can I get a mean annual raster layer from these 52?

The Raster calculator will do this but as its operators are all basic maths ones it will be a little longwinded. Is there a better/simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from QGIS 3.16 you can perform cell-based statistics natively using [Cell Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMHeZ.png) tool. For your case, you can use `Mean` cells as a statistic method to calculate the mean of all 52 rasters.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a GRASS GIS tool [`r.series`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.series.html) in the Processing Toolbox.

QGIS 2.18.18 Interface:

[image]

1. Start `r.series`
2. Select all layers (or select required layers)
3. Check `'Propagate NULLs'` if you have NoData in your rasters
4. Select `average`

Comment: thanks @Kazuhito that was easy to follow, BUT it fails: "line 395, in processAlgorithm if isinstance(out, QgsProcessingOutputHtml): NameError: name  QgsProcessingOutputHtml' is not defined". I am using QGIS 3.01

Comment: line 395, in processAlgorithm if isinstance(out, QgsProcessingOutputHtml): NameError: name QgsProcessingOutputHtml' is not defined

Comment: Thanks @Goomer I cannot reproduce that error myself, but it may be related to this post [Error running r.thin in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277486/error-running-r-thin-in-qgis). Does the process give you the output?

Comment: looks like something is broken in the installation. I get the same error with all of the raster GRASS tools I have tried so far. I reinstalled QGIS but still get the same error.

Comment: Seems it is a bug in 3.01:  http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Principal-Components-Analysis-Problem-td5361041.html#a5361300