Adding Raster Layers without losing non-overlaying Raster Values
I have a question relating to the Raster Calculator.
I have four individual Raster layer, which have Raster Values in different regions. I want to figure out the mean-Raster-Value of the Raster values that overlap, while keeping the Raster Values, which don't overlap with other Raster Values (e.g. I want to keep them, when there is just NoDataValue in the other Raster Layer).
I tried to figure it out on my own, but didn't come to any kind of conclusion.

I'm using QGIS.

See the answers of this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279958/creating-mean-raster-layer-from-set-of-raster-layers-in-qgis
